# How to change how the URL is displayed without changing the name of the controller? (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How could I change how the URL is displayed without changing the name of the controller? (Rails4)

Here is my static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def example
  end
end
```

Here is my routes.rb

```
get 'static_pages/example'
```

So "rake routes" gives

```
static_pages_example GET    /static_pages/example(.:format)         static_pages#example
```

The URL is now test.com/static_pages/example

Without changing the controller name, how could I change it to be for example: test.com/pages/example ? So that the 'static_pages' would always redirect to e.g. 'pages'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :static_pages, path: "pages" do #-> url.com/pages/example
   get :example, on: :collection
end
```

---

The Rails routing structure is actually extremely versatile.

Above is how you *should* do it (notice the [`path:` switch](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources-label-Options)).

If you wanted to use a standalone route (as in your example), you could use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
scope module: 'pages' do
   get :example, to: "static_pages#example" #-> url.com/pages/example
end
```

or...

```
#config/routes.rb
get "pages/example", to: "static_pages#example" #url.com/pages/example
```

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your route in your routes.rb

```
get 'pages/example', to: 'static_pages#example'
```